# In the Dresden Files RPG is it possible to get mental armor, and if so, how?

Tags: spells, dresden-files, armor, stress, damage-reduction

My character is a Wizard, and I've always been annoyed at how I can only cast up to 4 spells per scene (at least without going into consequences). So it got me thinking if there was a way around it. If i could somehow get mental armor, even just armor:1, it would allow me to cast as many spells as i wanted (assuming they stay under my conviction). I just can't think of a way to get that. please help.

Possibly relevant character stats:

Conviction and Lore +5
Discipline +4

Mental stress 4 boxes + 1 free mental mild consequence

2 available enchanted item slots

+1 control to spirit, fire, and earth evocation specializations

+1 control to Ward Thaumaturgy specialization

Evocation elements: Spirit, Fire, Earth

Comment: Not an answer to your current question, but if you want more spells, take a look at using your item slots for potions. One use per adventure, but you get two per focus item slot, (what are you using your item slots for right now?) you can make up what it is at the time of use, and their strength is decided by your lore. I've run a character who used potions, using spells as a backup. It works better than anyone suspects.

Answer (score 10):

**If you could do so, that would be an abuse rather than a use of the system.**

That said, on (YS250) in the 'flavor text' in the sidebar to the left, your question is asked and answered, i.e.

> Hey, Billy can you take a stunt, or cast a spell, or make an item of
>   some kind that gives you armor against the mental stress caused by
>   casting a spell?
>
> Good question!  And no, you can't.  Armor just doesn't help against
>   stress you inflict on yourself.

Comment: Do you think the emphasis on "*all* physical stress" in Inhuman Toughness (YS185) implies that it specifically ignores this general rule? Because if so, there's a blood mage build I could write an answer around...

Comment: I think this rule is meant to be a catch all, i.e. armor doesn't help against stress you inflict on yourself.  Think about your blood mage that slashes his palm to power his spell.  If it worked against self-inflicted physical stress, how would he cut himself?